# How to link product in parent category to same product in sub category

Tags: product, category, product-linking

I've got a **parent category** (clothing) and a **subcategory** (jeans). There's a **product** called "hip blue jeans", which is assigned **ONLY** to the subcategory "jeans" and **NOT** to it's parent category "clothing".

The parent category "clothing" is set as anchor.

If I navigate to the parent category "clothing" in frontend the product "hip blue jeans" will show up. 
If I click it I will be linked to "Shop" -> "Categories" -> "Clothing" (to the parent category) -> "hip blue jeans", **BUT** I want to be navigated to "Shop" -> "Categories" -> "Clothing" -> "**jeans**" (directly to the sub category) -> "hip blue jeans".

Is there any way to archive this?